# What is the green checkmark on Keystone Skill?

Tags: path-of-exile

I just noticed a little green checkmark on one of my (not yet taken) keystone skills:

[image]

After i placed a skillpoint there, and applied, the checkmark vanished. Other Keystones that i could put points into do not have this checkmark.

Does anyone know what this checkmark means?

Answer (score 1):

This is a challenge leftover from the Season 1 challenges. Season one ran from June 5th through October 8, 2013.

> Allocate all notable and all keystone passive skills. **A green check mark will appear next to skills you have taken.** The check mark remains even if the skill is refunded or the character deleted.

Chances are you'll see this type of challenge again once the new race season starts.

[Path of Exile Gamepedia](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Challenges)

Answer (score 1):

Back in the previous 4 month seasons, it was related to the Challenges (where you had to get all the notable nodes at same point).

The ticks have remained on some nodes as a bug, but this is fixed in patch 1.0.1, according to the patch notes:

```
Fixed an issue where check marks would appear on Notable and Keystone passive skills, even though there is currently no related challenge.
```

Answer (score 0):

it's a bug, it's a leftover from achievements. Simple as that.